# htaccess /profil.php?username=username to /username

Tags: .htaccess

I need help with my profile pages. My current .htaccess code is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /profil.php?username=$1
```

I want it to look like `myurl.com/username` and not like `myurl.com/profil.php?username=username`

Comment: This looks correct, can you tell us what issue/error you are seeing?

Comment: "Sidan du söker finns inte..." It's swedish for "The page you're looking for don't exists" Can it be my host? @miah

Comment: A couple other things: Is mod_rewrite enabled on your server?  Does it say which page is missing(with a full url)?

Comment: I'm new to htaccess codes so I dont know about mod_rewrite, and I'm currently using a webhotel from https://www.citynetworkhosting.com/

Comment: Oups missed to tag you @miah ^

Comment: try it without the `/` in front of `profil.php`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a RewriteCond to stop the infinite loop of redirects.

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(profil\.php)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /profil.php?username=$1
```